# How to know what you can import from package?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

Let's say there is no intellisense for node packages in Visual studio code(Sometimes intellisense doesn't work properly for a package it can't intellisense some field in the package), how do you know what you can import ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search directly in the source code (in the node_modules folder there is a folder called as the package, find module.exports or export keywords) or check the documentation if there is one.

Comment: Actually I articulated my question wrong, how intellisense searches for package exports, and decides what you can import from it?

Comment: It directly and simply (not easy haha) read and parse the source code and extract the informations it needs, here the exported modules, functions, variables...

Answer (score 1):

You could get every key of the imported variable

```js
const fs = require('fs');
console.log(Object.keys(module))
// ["writeFile","readdir","readdirSync",...]
```

Unless what's imported is a class for example when you'd have to get it's .prototype value. This will give you every function and property listed in the module exported object